# ios 11 sms app param does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="sms:+24321&body=This%20is%20the%20body">Click Me!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When you click the link above, iOS successfully opens the native iOS Messages application. If the user previously had the iOS Messages app open in the background on their phone, then iOS properly passes in the query parameters contained in the link, e.g. to: (24321) and body: (This is the body), but if the user does NOT already have iOS Messages open, then iOS opens Messages, but does NOT open a message w/ to and body filled out.

This is not an issue on iOS 10, it seems to have been introduced in iOS 11.

Comment: Calling `openURL` twice did not solve the issue for me in *iOS 11.1* but I checked in latest *iOS 11.2.1* and its fixed in this update.

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly an iOS 11 bug.

The same bug there is with the openURL, with this code, without the if state, we have the same results:

```
NSString *sms = @"sms:+1234567890&body=This is sms body.";
NSString *url = [sms stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 11.0)
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

With a double call it firstly open the message app and then pass the right parameters.

With a double call it works but it is a **BAD** workaround!

The same should happens with a web code.

I can only advise you to report a bug to Apple at [this](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) link.

This answer is not for the bounty, I just wanted to share with you my test. ;)

Comment: already reported to apple, they are saying we don't have exact time to fix for this